# C++20: g++ internal compiler error when std::lexicographical_compare_three_way third and fourth argument are reverse iterators

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

When I try to compile this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> d={1,2};
    std::vector<int> e={1,2};
    std::cout << (std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(d.begin(),d.end(),e.rbegin(),e.rend())==0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with gcc 11.1.0 and this flags

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++20
```

I get this output from g++:

```
In file included from c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from test2.cpp:1:
c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr decltype (__comp((* __first1), (* __first2))) std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(_InputIter1, _InputIter1, _InputIter2, _InputIter2, _Comp) [with _InputIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _InputIter2 = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >; _Comp = std::compare_three_way; decltype (__comp((* __first1), (* __first2))) = std::strong_ordering]':
c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:1872:35:   required from 'constexpr auto std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(_InputIter1, _InputIter1, _InputIter2, _InputIter2) [with _InputIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _InputIter2 = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >]'
test2.cpp:8:54:   required from here
c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:1861:24:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'std::operator==<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >(((const std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >&)(& __first2)), ((const std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >&)(& __last2)))'
c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:494:22:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '(& __x)->std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >::base()'
c:\program files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.1.0-mingw-w64-8.0.0-r1\mingw64\include\c++\11.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:1861:36: internal compiler error: in cxx_eval_indirect_ref, at cp/constexpr.c:4976
 1861 |       return (__first2 == __last2) <=> true; // See PR 94006
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
```

Is this a compiler bug?

I get this error only when the third and fourth arguments are reverse iterators. If I use reverse iterators in the first and second argument, but not in the third and the fourth, g++ doesn't complain.

Comment: Well, the compiler says to file a bug report, so yes, it's a compiler bug. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: fwiw, [clang compiles it](https://godbolt.org/z/xezbb8YW1), though even if there was an error in your code, your code should never make the compiler break apart. "internal error" is always an internal error of the compiler

Comment: @cigien Is it a _known_ compiler bug? I did some research and I found nothing, but it seemed strange to me that nobody else had ever noticed this, so I decided to ask. In case nobody knows what this is about or if there is already a bug report for this, I will file a bug report.

Comment: I'm not aware of this bug myself, but you should definitely search through bugzilla before filing a report.

Comment: Do you know Kevlin Henney? He usually has examples of bugs exposing implementation details to users in his presentations. No idea if he would like this one, but I find the `// See PR 94006` quite interesting: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94006. Not sure if this is just coincidence or whether the bug you encountered has anything to do with a fix of PR94006, though 10.3 seems to not have the bug you encountered: https://godbolt.org/z/4xv5zW8hj

Comment: probably not a "fix" of 94006, but i could imagine that someone replaced the original with `return (__first2 == __last2) <=> true;` because 94006 pointed out that it is more efficient, and that could have caused your bug